# Stack overflow in c++ with vc++ 2010

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I have met a stack overflow in a program compiled using vc++ 2010. I open a debugger and attached it to the process.
Then I force the program to continue after the stack overflow error, every time there would be an access violation error.

My question is: is the access violation error caused by the stack overflow?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In Windows, stack overflow is detected by having an unreadable page of memory past the end of the stack. The first fault in this page raises a stack overflow exception. The next one raises an access violation.

But, to get to the core of the problem: don't do that. Stack overflows are not recoverable. Once you've had a stack overflow, your program is in an indeterminate state and you should just let it die.